# Why does Python allow stand-alone expressions?

Tags: python, language-design

In Python, this is a valid program

```
def PrintWorld():
    print('World')

print('Hello')
0
'beautiful'
True
None
0 < 0
3, 3
lambda c:3
PrintWorld()
```

All it does is print 'Hello World' on two lines. The expressions are `0`, `'beautiful'`, `True`, `None`, `0 < 0`, `3, 3`, and `lambda c:3` are ignored and I'm wondering why.

I realize that this behavior allows Python to treat the function call `PrintWorld()` like any expression: It is an expression with value `None` in the course of whose evaluation the function is called. In a sense, this means that both `'beautiful'`, `PrintWorld()`, and a hypothetical expression with side effects like `PrintWorld() is None` could be treated the same on some level.

I also realize that this is related to interactive mode: When you run the Python interactively, giving only a stand-alone expression will result in its value being printed.

Still, why should non-interactive mode accept these expressions (except function calls)? In my eyes they open up the possibility for pointless code without offering anything in return.

And, as a follow-up: If you *do* allow these stand-alone expressions, why have comments or a `pass` statement in the language when you could just use a stand-alone expression instead?  Sure, "explicit is better than implicit", but it's also valuable to keep the language small.

As research I googled and searched stack overflow and CS stack exchange. I also looked into the Python language definition.

Comment: I think python just evaluates them. To use their values is up to you. It just makes "compiling" (its not a compiled language) python easier I guess, but honestly, Im not an expert in this area so I don't know.

Comment: [Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) and [simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#)

Comment: It is possible to define side effects for pretty much all of those expressions. You could hypothetically want to evaluate an expression for the side effects

Comment: @mousetail How would you do that for the examples I gave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The python creators decided that any expression is valid as a statement. While not all expressions are useful as statements, it would make the language more complex to have to remember which expressions may be statements and which can not.

A second reason is that many expressions that may seem "safe" can still have side effects, making it useful to evaluate them without using the return value.

### Operators

Operators are the most obvious examples of expressions that you can easily add side-effects to. In your example `0 < 0` is equivalent to `0.__le__(0)`. You can overwrite the `__le__` method or any operator special method to do whatever you want, including writing to a file or incrementing a counter.

You can also evaluate operator expressions just to make sure the types are compatible. For example, if you are going to do a very long computation on variables `a` and `b` that ends by dividing some value based on `a` by `b` you might evaluate `a/b` at the start of your function as a quick and dirty way to make sure the types can be divided and that `b` is not zero before spending a lot of time calculating.

### Strings

Strings don't typically have any side effects, but string expressions are frequently used in python code as a type of comment. Specifically, docstrings are triple-quoted strings right after the heading of a class or function, and will be assigned to `__doc__`.

### Variables

Evaluating variables has one important function: It will crash if the variable doesn't exit. For example, suppose I have a module `server.py` that must be configured `server.host = 'localhost'` before starting. I could write this:

```
try:
    host
except NameError:
    raise ConfigurationException("must set host")
```

### Tuples

The tuple expression `a, b` where `a` and `b` are expressions will evaluate any side effects from `a`  `b`.

### Others

Ok, there is little use for a loose `None`. However, only disallowing `None`, `True`, `False`, `Ellipsis`, `NotImplemented`, and `...` would be a unnecessary special case that would make the language harder to learn for little benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Python can be used interactively, in which case the bare expression's value (if any, it might be `None`) is printed out. If running a script or as part of a function, the value is just discarded.

If you look closely, Python only has functions (no `procedure`s in e.g. Pascal sense or `SUBROUTINE` for Fortran that specifically don't return a value at all). Like in C, procedures are fake, functions that return `None` either explicitly, doing a bare `return`, or by not executing `return` at all.

Why Python is architected this way is anybody's guess. You'd have to ask the people in charge. It does simplify the grammar somewhat and presumably also makes the parsing/processing simpler/faster, besides making interactive use cleaner.